# Derivatives of Incomplete Gamma Distribution

Tags: partial-derivative, gamma-function

I'm trying to understand how Wolfram_alpha reached this equation:

So far i reached:
$$ \frac{\partial\Gamma(a,x)}{\partial a} = \frac{\partial}{\partial a}\int_x^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t}dt = \int_x^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t}ln(t)dt $$

in which $\ln(t)$ is the natural logarithm of $t$.
According to Wolfram_alpha it can be rewritten as:

$$ \frac{\partial\Gamma(a,x)}{\partial a} = \Gamma(a)^2z^a \,_2F_2(a,a;a+1,a+1;-x)-\Gamma(a,0,x)ln(x)+\Gamma(a)\psi(a) $$

Source: http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/20/01/01/0002/

Comment: if someone as me doesn't understood the terms:

In which:
$$\,_pF_q(a_1,...,a_p;b_1,...,b_q;x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(a_1)_k...(a_p)_k}{(b_1)_k...(b_q)_k}\frac{x^k}{k!} $$  denotes the generalized hypergeometric function; $$(a)_k = \frac{\Gamma(a+n)}{\Gamma(a)} = (a+n-1)(a+n-2)...(a+1)(a)$$ dentotes the Pochhammer symbol and$$\Gamma(a,x_1,x_2) = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} t^{a-1}e^{-t}dt $$ is the generalized incomplete gamma function.

Comment: Else, one could write:
$$ \frac{\partial\Gamma(a,x)}{\partial a} = \Gamma(a)^2z^aa^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(a+k)^2}\frac{z^k}{k!}-\Gamma(a,0,x)ln(x)+\Gamma(a)\psi(a) $$